# Problem with reading string from a file in C

Tags: c, string, file, eof

I've tried to look for a similar problem but was unable to find it so I'm posting this. Here's the thing.
Let's say I have a file named text.txt. Now, the file consists of 3 integers and string, something like this:

```
4 59 32 This is sentence 1
5 9 130 Grass is green
3 12 149 I need help
```

I'm still learning C so I'm sorry if this is some easy type question etc. Here's the problem. I don't know how to read this. The same is if the string is at the beginning of the file like this

```
This is sentence 1 4 59 32
Grass is green 5 9 130 
I need help 3 12 149
```

I know how to read it if I know the amount of words it will consist of (like if the file would be something like Name Surname Number Number Number) but this when I need to read entire, I have no idea.

Here's the code from comments. However, as @john pointed out, it's false right from the start since i gets first character and then I do scanf (still, I've tried out and with only numbers involved, fscanf gets correct values even though first character is read).
I was also thinking about some while loop with isalpha() and isspace() involved but to no avail.

```
while((i = fgetc(input)) != (int)(EOF))
    {
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);

        j=0;
        while(i != (int)('\n'))
        {
            string[j++]=(char)i;
            i = fgetc(inputFile);
        }
        string[j] = '\0';

        printf("%d %d %d %s\n",br1, br2, br3, string);
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you need to provide a [mcve], it is off-topic without that.

Comment: @OznOg I was trying something like this:

while((i = fgetc(input)) != (int)(EOF))
    {
        fscanf(inputFile, "%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
        
        j=0;
        while(i != (int)('\n'))
        {
            string[j++]=(char)i;
            i = fgetc(inputFile);
        }
        string[j] = '\0';

        printf("%d %d %d %s\n",br1, br2, br3, string);

So, idea here was to read those three integers and then to go character by character until I reach the end of line. However, this is not working.

Comment: @TonyReirdan The first thing is to decide which format. The second is obviously harder since there's no simple way to distinguish a number from a word, so forget about that and try the first. As you say the trick is to read three integers first and then the rest of the line. But your code doesn't do that, it starts by reading a character, not the first three integers.

Comment: @OznOg Yeah, sorry, I've done it now.

Comment: Consider using `fgets()` to read a _line_, and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

> it's false right from the start since i gets first character and then I do scanf

You're right, it's wrong. There's no need to consume a line's first character just to test for EOF - we can leave that to `fscanf()`.
Also there's no need to read the string's characters one by one - `fscanf()` can read a string ending at `\n` with the conversion specification `%[^\n]`.
If the input string length is not limited, we'd have to prevent the buffer overflow when the input string would need more memory than provided by `string` by adding a *maximum field width*. If you defined e. g. `char string[100];`, the maximum field width is 99, since the last `char` is needed for the terminating null character.
So we could write e. g.

```
    while (fscanf(input, "%d %d %d %99[^\n]", &num1, &num2, &num3, string) == 4)
        printf("%d %d %d %s\n", num1, num2, num3, string);
```